# Python/Twisted: exceptions.RuntimeError: doWrite called on a twisted.internet.tcp.Port

Tags: python, twisted

We have this gem of an exception being thrown during start-up of an application, when clients aren't even connected or even trying to connect, as well as when clients start to connect once the system has initialised,

```
[twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 88, in callWithLogger
        return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 73, in callWithContext
        return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 619, in _doReadOrWrite
        why = selectable.doWrite()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1117, in doWrite
        "doWrite called on a %s" % reflect.qual(self.__class__))
    exceptions.RuntimeError: doWrite called on a twisted.internet.tcp.Port
[twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory] (TCP Port 37605 Closed)
[twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory] Stopping factory <twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory instance at 0x7f25262bcab8>
```

The application is written in python 2.7.6 with Twisted 13.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, kernel 3.13.0-34. We do not see this exception when running the same code on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04, have not tried on any other OS's.

The performance of the system is unpredictable at best when this exception is thrown. In some instances there seems to be no noticeable loss in performance and the clients can connect and disconnect at will and data communication integrity is solid and the software just works. In other instances the clients can only connect once on a port and then when the client disconnected the client can not longer connect on that port. Finally there are times when the clients just cannot connect to the port at all, it is as if the reactor stops listening on that port??

I can't see any reference to my code in the traceback, so I'm at a loss where to start looking for a fix.

The best reference I have found to this issue is [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4759), however, the thread just seems to go nowhere without a solution?

Has anyone run into this before and found a fix, or work around or just had a fir of rage and tossed the computer out the window?

Cheers

Comment: Note my comment on the ticket you linked to: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4759#comment:4

Comment: Hi Jean-Paul, Thanks for your feedback, I appreciate the big guns providing input with this matter :). The reason I did not progress the proposed recommendation from the thread originally was due to no positive response regarding that wok around. Anyway, I have now implemented that assert into epollreactor.addWrite, and all other reactors just to be sure, as you suggested. The traceback is still the same? Note, unlike that thread this issue is highly repeatable and I am happy to try any further suggestions or debug. Cheers.

Comment: Hi DanM.  Thanks for trying this out and sharing your results.  To be clear, the proposed change wasn't a workaround.  It was meant to gather more information to try to track down the cause.  `doWrite` should only be called on "writers" added to the reactor.  `addWriter` should be the only way that a writer can be added to the reactor.  The assert should have caused `addWriter` to refuse to add anything as a writer that isn't actually a writer (and by raising an exception, should have pointed out which code was responsible for trying to add that object).

Comment: The fact that this didn't change anything is discouraging and now that I look into things in more detail, I see that `Port` actually claims to implement `IWriteDescriptor`. :(  So instead I guess the assertion should be `assert not isinstance(writer, Port)` where `Port` is `twisted.internet.tcp.Port`.  Note that I recommended editing `SelectReactor.addWriter` - you also need to make sure you edit the right `addWriter` method (`SelectReactor` used to be the default on most platforms but that's changed - so check which reactor you're using and make sure you edit its method)

Comment: Jean-Paul, we made the updates suggested and still we get the same result, same RuntimeError being thrown. Just to confirm the system defaults to using the epollReactor and the updates were made to the epollReactor.addWriter method, however to be sure we updated all other reactors just to make sure. Any further suggestion for debug will be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: I wonder if you have a minimal, self-contained example that I could use to reproduce this behavior.  Apart from that, the problem here is that somehow the reactor is interpreting some epoll result to mean a port is writeable.  This should never happen since ports can't be writeable.  A port should never be added to the reactor to be monitored for writeability.  And even if it is, epoll should never tell the reactor that it has become writeable.  `addWriter` was the obvious place for something to go wrong... but the problem could come from elsewhere.

Comment: It might be better continue this further on the Twisted ticket I linked to where the space constraints aren't so tight. :)